# high-level interpretation of the transpose of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The dot product of to vectors $v$ and $w$ is often defined as $dot(v, w) = v^T w$. This is usually done in the context of matrix representations and assuming that a vector is a column matrix. However, if we think of vectors in more abstract terms, we don't necessarily have to define a basis, let alone think of them as lists of numbers or column matrices. Does it even make sense to talk about the "transpose of a vector" in this abstract way of thinking?

At most, I can think of the transpose of a "linear transformation" (that could, but doesn't have to, be represented as a matrix) $M$, which we could define as an operation that satisfies the following rule: $dot(Mv, w) = dot(v, M^T w)$, which I think is a definition that has some high-level meaning if we think of $M v$ as the result of applying the linear transformation $M$ on $v$, and the dot product as a function defined on two vectors; we never had to refer to matrices or lists of numbers. However, does the "transpose of a vector" have any useful high-level interpretation (does it yield a new vector? a new linear transformation?) or is it just a convenient notation that only makes sense if we assume that we are working with matrix representations?

Comment: Dual Spaces? Adjoint maps?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think that's what I've been looking for, but I'm not very familiar with the terms. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think @amd has given the bare bones of the subject. I don't feel up to rewriting what is in every text book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a vector space $V$ over the field $K$, the dual space $V^*$ consists of linear functionals $\alpha:V\to K$. Given a basis $\{e^1,\dots,e^n\}$ of $V$, its dual basis is a basis $\{\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n\}$ of $V^*$ such that $\varepsilon_i[e^j]=\delta_{ij}$. If you represent elements of $V^*$ as row vectors, then, relative to a pair of dual bases, applying an element of $V^*$ to a vector in $V$ becomes matrix multiplication. You can then interpret the transpose operation in $v^Tw$ as a linear map that sends basis vectors of $V$ to their duals.

The transpose of a matrix also has a connection to dual spaces. The *adjoint* $T^*$ of a linear operator $T:V\to W$ is the linear map $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ (note the reversal of direction) such that for $\beta\in W^*$ and $v\in V$, $(T^*\beta)[v]=\beta[Tv]$. It turns out that if $M$ is the matrix of $T$ relative to a pair of bases for $V$ and $W$, then $M^T$ is the matrix of $T^*$ relative to their duals.

(If the underlying field is $\mathbb C$, then you’ll need to use conjugate transposes instead.)

Comment: "If you represent elements of $V^∗$ as row vectors"

I wanted to avoid this kind of representation-dependent interpretation in the first place. However, as you say in the first paragraph, we can interpret $v^T$ as $v^T:V \rightarrow K $, which would make the expression $v^Tw$ make more sense, but I don't follow exactly how this results in the dot product.

Comment: @MeiZhang How are you going to avoid a representation-dependent interpretation when the *dot* product (as opposed to some more abstractly-defined *inner* product) is inherently representation dependent? Anyway, the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) makes the connection between linear functionals and inner products.

Comment: I see, that was my mistake, I should have said inner product instead of dot product.